# Ошибка в phpsrorm. No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance

Tags: php, mysql

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in ..\account.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null ..\account.php on line 13

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in ..\account.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ..\account.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in ..\account.php on line 17

Ошибка: No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu (Alt+Enter). Please configure SQL dialect for this file. Advanced features such as code completion, navigation and inspection will be activated.

[image: картинка]

Comment: справа вкладка database, подключись к своей базе данных и ошибки пропадут.

Comment: Попробуйте `$CONNECT` и строку с запросом поменять местами. Т.к. `mysql_query()` первым параметром как раз запрос ожидает.

Answer (score 5):

Включаем закладку "Базы данных" View -> Tool windows -> Database
На ней подключаем ту же базу данных к которой обращаемся в коде PHP

Также желательно указать диалект SQL (PL SQL, T-SQL, mySQL), т.к. у них немного разный синтаксис, и поэтому PHPStorm тоже ругается. Вот инструкция где указывать: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/sql-dialects.html